# How would I copy over rows of a dataframe to another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to go through an excel spreadsheet that contains lots of data and sort through it.  The image following is just a short pic of what I have.  I imported this excel sheet into a dataframe.  What I need to do is split up the data by data point name into different data frames

The Datapoints go from 1066 to 1070 in increments of 1.  I need to split these into different dataframes so theres an dataframe for each.  Any help would be appreciated.  I have already imported it into a dataframe which I called test_df_new.  I just need to know how to go further.

Thank you

I want 
[image]

Comment: there is alot of work involved can you paste the output of database instead of image so I can copy it.

Comment: There are 2901 entries in the dataframe.  Would you want me to post the entire thing or just like 40 or 50?

Comment: Data point EN1068QR suppose to be same?

Comment: The letters at the end of the EN10xx change based on a tool.  I just want it to sort based on EN10xx for now.  The rest I can deal with later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your asked to sort by a column in comments you can use sort column like this

```
import pandas as pd
_data = {'Toolset': ['Toolset','Toolset','Toolset','Toolset'],
        'Data Point Name': ['EN1068','EN1067','EN1068QR','EN1068QR'],
        'Toolset Start Date':[0,0,0,0],
        'ToolsetCount':[1674,1160,977,977],
        'ToolsetCap':[0,0,0,0],
        'Toolset Cap Start Date':[0,0,0,0],
        'Cap Count':[0,0,51,42]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=_data)
df.sort_values(by=['Data Point Name'])
```

[image]

Note: Since they start with EN pandas will take care of the sorting by alphabet. I have attached an image is this what your are looking for?

and you can also use copy() function to copy df to new df like this:
new_df = df.copy()

Comment: Thank you Jaskaran but would you know how to move values that start with EN1068 into another dataframe and values that start with EN1069 into another.  I want 5 different dataframes because the data point name contains EN1066, 1067, 1068, 1069 and 1070.  I wanted 5 DFs and put all rows that have a data point name that beings with EN1XXX into the corresponding dataframe

Comment: you can store all unique values from Data Point Name to a list and use sort by on that list.
then use 
df3 = df[(df['Data Point Name'] == 'EN1067')]
something like this and read value from that list you saved above to separate all value.
I cannot answer on purity of it. But it will work